# iTunes: Unable to sync playlist that missing from "Sync Music" option

Tags: itunes, iphone

I'm unable to sync playlists to my iPhone because they simply won't show in iTunes' "Sync Music" screen.

For example, in iTunes (on my desktop), I have several playlist folders.  One folder has 18 playlists.  When I select my phone & click "Music", I'm taken to the "Sync Music" option.  When I look at that same folder, I see only 11 playlists.  *7 are missing!*

It's not just this folder either, it happens with several folders & playlists.

I can't find rhyme or reason to it.  It's not related to being a "smart" playlist.  If I create a new playlist & move one song to the new playlist, it still doesn't show.  I've restarted, I've reconnected my iPhone, etc.  I've tried create a new folder & moving music there.  No luck across the board.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It seems you trailed off in the middle of a sentence.  What did you mean to say when you wrote "It's not just this folder...".  Additionally, what version of iTunes and iOS are you running?

Comment: Sorry, updated.  I'm on my laptop, but I can check the specific versions of my desktop when I'm home.  I'd check for updates, so everything should be pretty current.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your syncing, try to (simply) drag and drop the playlist(s) to your iPhone, while connected to iTunes.

Make sure that syncing is enabled (especially for podcasts and other categories of media, especially if your syncing more than just "music".

If that doesn't work, the following common solutions work for several different problems, can't hurt to try them.

1. Ensure that you have enough space on your iPhone.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Restart your iPhone.

Comment: Already tried those things, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, the most likely cause of your missing music is that you have some downloads in itunes that have not been resumed. For more information on solving this problem you can check this link http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1408

Comment: No luck.  I've tried creating a new playlist using only media that shows on existing (and sync'able) playlists.